# Facebook Invite VC displaying weird

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios8

I am having a problem using the new Facebook SDK invite system. The view controller which appears when using FBSDKAppInviteDialog displays very oddly, then disappears before the user has time to interact with it.

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
//content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg"];
FBSDKAppInviteDialog *inviteDialog = [[FBSDKAppInviteDialog alloc] init];
if ([inviteDialog canShow]) {
    inviteDialog.content = content;
    inviteDialog.delegate = self;
    [inviteDialog show];
}
```

This is what appears on the screen when the modal launches:
[image: Failing invite screen]

Does anyone know of any reason this would happen?

Edit[Sep 8, 2015 15:15 EDT]: We are currently getting an error code of 1; unknown error. Here is the exact print out:

```
Failed to perform app invite: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.Facebook.platform error 1.)
Full Report => {
}
```

We thought it might be that we don't have friend permissions or something to do with iOS 9; however we are running our test on iOS 8, and we added friend permissions, and we have not seen a change.

Answer (score 0):

I would call the `validateWithError` function they provided.  It might give an idea of what the issue is.

[FBSDKAppInviteDialog documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAppInviteDialog/)